# I am trying to make a json for the jolt transform but I am stuck in nested array format

Tags: java, php, arrays, jolt

I am trying to do Transform the jolt but I face problems in the nested array. I am not getting the description value.
I put some code
JSON Input is

```
{
  "id": 3,     
  "name": "Sample Product",
  "attribute_set_id": 4,
  "price" : 10,
 "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "image",
      "value": "/1/_/1.jpg"
    },        
    {
      "attribute_code": "description",
      "value": "<p>This is Sample Product for test</p>"
    }        
  ]  
}
```

And my Jolt Spec is

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",         
      "name": "name",
      "description": "custom_attributes[0].attribute_code.value"
    }
]
```

My expected output is

```
{
  "id" : 3,
  "name" : "Sample Product",
 "description" : "<p>This is Sample Product for test</p>",
 "image" : "/1/_/1.jpg",
 "start_price" : 10,
 "current_price" : 10
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `"attribute_code": "image"` and `"attribute_code": "description"` always appears in the 1st and 2nd element of the array, you can simply transform the given JSON string with following Jolt Spec:

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "id",
      "name": "name",
      "custom_attributes": {
        "1": {
          "value": "description"
        },
        "0": {
          "value": "image"
        }
      },
      "price": ["start_price", "current_price"]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: but I do for same code for Image like 
"custom_attributes": {
        "1": {
          "value": "image"
        }
      }
its throw the error: duplicate key

Comment: @Krunal Pandya I tested it on [Jolt Transform Demo](http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/), it is OK! You just rename the key from description to image.

Comment: no man I want both of them and in my actual code there is more than 15 custom_attributes and I want 5 of them.

Comment: @Krunal Pandya I have updated my post. You can expand it if you want to retrieve more elements in the array with specific index.

Comment: I have price value and I have to add it to in diff variables I edit my question Please look into it.

Comment: @Krunal Pandya The answer has been updated and you should post another question rather than extend original question.